# Image display using datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Here is my code which I used image slider display image using `datalist` but I don't have any idea how can I display big image when image slide here is my code:

```
  <div id="photos" class="galleryview">
  <img src="images/home_gallery/banner1.jpg" />
  <div style="margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px">
    <asp:DataList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="dl_Images" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dl_Images_ItemDataBound"
      OnItemCommand="dl_Images_ItemCommand">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="filmstrip">
          <div class="panel">
            <a href="" id="img_href" runat="server">
              <div class="panel-overlay" align="left">
                <li>
                  <asp:Image BorderColor="#ececec" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" runat="server"
                    ID="i_ProductImage" Width="104" Height="104" />
                </li>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div align="center" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
              <asp:LinkButton ToolTip='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
                CommandName="lbclick" ID="lb_productID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'
                CssClass="bule-link"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
            <%--<asp:Label ID="l_ProductId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ProductId") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
  </div>
</div>
```